# integrity of unreinforced 6-inch concrete slab floor for a 15mx20mx1.8m pool

Tags: floor, construction, pool, slab

Our church built an in-ground pool with the following dimensions: 15m x 20m x 1.8m (roughly 540cum) in our retreat center. However, no reinforcing bars were added when a 6-inch thick floor slab was poured. Retaining walls are concrete-reinforced riprapped boulders. Any thoughts on the integrity of the floor slab when the pool is eventually filled with water?

Comment: Was the pool designed by a qualified engineer or architect?

Comment: How was the base prepared below the slab? Are you on a hill? In a seismic zone? Based on the info provided, there's not much we can tell you.

Comment: @jwh20 good point.   churches (and I'm a member in an American Baptist Church) can get pretty "gungho"   and just get a bunch of folks together and "get 'er done". It's hard to slow them down and say, hey, let's do this right and get it permitted and engineered.

Comment: You said "no reinforcing bars."  Was galvanized reinforcing mesh used?  I would not be comfortable with an un-reinforced concrete slab for this application, irrespective of how well the ground below the slab was prepared.

Comment: The weight of the water will be evenly distributed, the problem is it all depends on to what level the earth below was compacted, I hope they at least used fiberglass in the mix it is quite strong, when we used to build pools in the 70’s we only used welded wire, but these pools had liners so cracks were not a problem, we also used a mix of zonalite and concrete no engineering and only 4” thick the most important thing was the compaction prior to the pour/ the bottom and sides were shot in with a special pump, the concrete doesn’t need to be very thick but if the ground moves cracks will form

Comment: It breaks, or it does not. Nothing to do about it **now** - it's already built. See if it breaks, when it breaks, see about remediation.